# Error: cannot find php_pdo_driver.h when installing pdo_pgsql in Mac Mojave

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, mamp, php-pgsql

I am trying to add a PHP module in my mamp stack (version 7.2.19). I have been following the guidelines in [`bitnami; mamp pdo_pgsql` module](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/mamp/configuration/install-modules-php/) but it gives me an error when I execute the command:

```
./configure --with-pdo-pgsql=/Applications/PostgreSQL
```

Where have I gone wrong?

I am using PHP Version 7.2.19.